# Value of the function. (First order set theory foundations ZFC. Interpretation with partial functions.)

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, foundations

I am convinced that the following is true, I just need to double check myself, and also maybe share this with a community, since I find it beautiful.(if it is true)

Let us consider "the standard foundations of mathematics" the first order set theory ZFC.

It has model that using partial functions:
(see article [WILLIAM M. FARMER,
JOSHUA D. GUTTMAN: A Set Theory with Support for Partial Functions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20016214) )

Let's define value of the function the following way:
$"f(x)" := (\iota y: \langle x,y\rangle \in f)$
(here
$f$ and $x$ are object variables, and iota is THE definite description operator :) ).

Without a doubt, the following sequence is valid:

$(\langle x,y\rangle \in f) \Rightarrow (f(x)=y)$

My claim is that the opposite implication is also valid:

$(f(x)=y) \Rightarrow (\langle x,y\rangle \in f)$

Because

1. if $x\in \mbox{dom}(f)$(don't pay attention to parenthesis here: it can be rewritten) is true under fixed interpretation and fixed evaluation of object variables then it is true implication.
2. if it is not, then (f(x)=y) is automatically a false formula under fixed interpretation and evaluation. (This claim is based on interpretation with partial functions, described in the article.) Therefore the implication is still true, as if it was "$\mbox{false}\Rightarrow \varphi$".

So the following formula/sequence is valid:
$(f(x)=y) \Leftrightarrow (\langle x,y\rangle \in f)$
and we can substitute one side of the equivalence with the other voluntarily in other proofs, without any need for any precautions.

Is everything correct?

Comment: I cannot speak to the exact syntactical requirements of the specific theory you are discussing, but in general in mathematics, a definition introduces a new symbol, and means that the new symbol is equivalent to the expression by which is defined, not just implied by that expression.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am sure that the definition is perfectly fine. It is similar to Metamath's "(f ` x)", but the difference is that as a semantics it has a partial function which is undefined when x is not in domain of f, but in Metamath in this case it is defined and equal to the empty set.